# Entering an array to the firstOrCreate generates an error Laravel 5.7

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am running the firstOrCreate on my controller with the following code:

```
private function validateNumberBD($areaCodes,$numbers){
    $arrayAreaCodes = array();
    foreach ($areaCodes as $key => $value) {
        $arrayAreaCodes[] = $value->AREACODES_ID;
    }

    $consultArray = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++){
        for($j = 0; $j < count($arrayAreaCodes);$j++){

            $consultArray[] = (['PHONE' => $numbers[$i],'AREACODES_ID' => $arrayAreaCodes[$j]]);


        }

    }
    //dd($consultArray);


    $searchOrCreate = Phone::firstOrCreate($consultArray);



}
```

My problem is generated since executing that code generates the following error:

[image]

If I do a dd () to my $ consultArray variable, it shows me the following array

[image]

If I change the position of the array values, I get this error:
[image]

Consulting the new array would look like this.
[image]

I think my mistake is in how to list the data, but I really don't know what else to do.

In query mode, how do I know how many values ​​the firstOrCreate creates for me?

Comment: Did you add the columns to `Phone::$fillable`?

Comment: Yes and `$primaryKey = 'PHONES_ID`

Answer (score 0):

firstOrCreate cannot check or insert multiple records and you are sending an array of arrays.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++){
        for($j = 0; $j < count($arrayAreaCodes);$j++){
            $searchOrCreate = Phone::::firstOrCreate(
            ['PHONE' => $numbers[$i], 'AREACODES_ID' => $arrayAreaCodes[$j]]);
        }
    }
```

This could work.

Comment: I imagined it in that sense, but the way you explain it we talk about more than 1000 queries to the database according to what my code itself does. That's why I tried to do it with the firstOrCreate

Comment: Yes I am aware. Maybe you can checkout insertOrIgnore() method. It is supposed to work on an array of data.